# Add custom CSS class to "add to cart" button on WooCommerce shop and archives pages based on certain condition

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to disable "add to cart" button on WooCommerce shop and archives pages if product's quantity stock is zero or less.

I don't want to hide it so I came up with the code below.

My issue is that code doesn't add style to element, it replaces the whole button code inside html tree so button is not displayed at all.

Any ideas on how to overcome the issue?

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'remove_price_from_variable_products', 9 );

function remove_price_from_variable_products() {
    global $product;

    if( $product->get_stock_quantity() <= 0 ) {
    ?>
    <style> 
        .add_to_cart_button {
            cursor: not-allowed !important;
        }
    </style>
    <?php
        
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'custom_content_addtocart_button', 100 );

    }
}


function custom_content_addtocart_button() {
    echo '<br/><div class="button-notice">Contact Us for more information</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add/edit/remove CSS classes from the existing add to cart button on WooCommerce shop and archives pages you can use the `woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_args` filter hook

So you get:

```php
function action_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_args( $wp_parse_args, $product ) {
    // Initialize
    $custom_class = '';
    
    // Certain condition, can be anything, in this specific case for the stock quantity. ADAPT TO YOUR NEEDS
    if ( $product->get_stock_quantity() <= 0 ) {
        $custom_class = 'button-not-allowed';
    }
    
    // NOT empty (from here on, no need to make any changes to my answer)
    if ( ! empty ( $custom_class ) ) {  
        // Class
        $wp_parse_args['class'] = implode(
            ' ',
            array_filter(
                array(
                    'button' . ' ' . $custom_class,
                    'product_type_' . $product->get_type(),
                    $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
                    $product->supports( 'ajax_add_to_cart' ) && $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ? 'ajax_add_to_cart' : '',
                )
            )
        );
    }

    return $wp_parse_args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_args', 'action_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_args', 10, 2 );
```

**Note:** the `$product->get_stock_quantity()` function is best used in combination with `$product->managing_stock()`, but this depends on your needs

---

Then apply the following CSS

```css
.button-not-allowed {
    cursor: not-allowed !important;
}
```

Comment: Did the job! Thank you so much. Lastly, any suggestion which is the correct hook to add the custom message after button?

Comment: @newbie For your additional question, see: [How to add a customizable text after WooCommerce add to cart button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69089143/11987538) or [How to add text underneath WooCommerce add to cart button based on product category](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61663211/11987538)